# Extend Lua language settings in Notepad++ to spell-check also stuff enclosed in `[[ ... ]]`

Tags: lua, notepad++, spell-checking

I am currently going through the lua files of [LaTeX's TikZ/PGF code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) and among other things I want to correct spelling errors because parts of these lua files are also used for the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

To do this I use Notepad++ but as it seems, stuff enclosed in `[[" ... "]]` is not spell-checked. Here an example from the file [DistanceMatrix.lua](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/master/tree/tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/lua/pgf/gd/phylogenetics/DistanceMatrix.lua) were I introduced a spelling error.

```
declare {
  key = "distance matrix verticess",
  type = "string",

  summary = [["
    A list of verticess that are used in the parsing of the
    |distance matrix| key. If this key is not used at all, all
    vertices of the graph will be used for the computation of a
    distance matrix.
  "]],
```

In the left of the following image one sees the result when `Lua` is the active language and on the right when `TeX` is the active language.

[image: image showing the above code in Notepad++ when using languages Lua (left) and TeX (right)]

As can be seen the word "verticess" is not underlined in the `summary` part when Lua is the active language.

Is it possible to extend/modify the Lua language in Notepad++ thus that also the parts enclosed in `[[" ... "]]` are spell-checked? (Maybe it would also be sufficient to spell-check stuff in `[[ ... ]]` thus without the quotes? Unfortunately I am not familiar with the Lua language.) And of course, if this is possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX is cheating somewhat based on how it's language style is defined. The TeX definition recognizes spelling errors in variable names: [image]

This can be an annoyance for many people.

If it is acceptable for your needs using an older version of DSpellCheck(1.3.5 or older) you can uncheck the `Check Only Comments and Strings if Possible` setting of DSpellCheck to apply it this behavior to all languages:

[image]

---

Example of Lua language setting after change:
[image]

Comment: What DsSpellCheck version you are using? The dialog in my version (1.4.9) looks different and does not offer an option to limit but only to exclude strings, comments, and now also functions from the inspection.

Comment: I am using version: 1.2.12.0

Comment: Thanks. That's a rather old version https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck/blob/master/Changes.md 
Worth a try, using an older version could be a workaround until this is fixed.

Comment: I see, I updated to 1.4.6 and even with all boxes check it does not spell check the multi line string. i am able to get it to catch the spelling error in a multi line comment, but not a multi line string

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior I have observed and investigated.

Comment: Reverting DSpellCheck to v1.3.5 indeed works fine. Now is the question if the behavior in the current version can be considered as a bug or a feature. Since you guys Nifim and @wp78de seem to be much more familiar with this stuff than me, it would be nice if one of you could provide a bug report or a feature request at DSpellCheck. For the time being I'll accept this answer. Many thanks again to both of you!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the [DSpellCheck](https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck) Plug-in for Notepad++ does not check **string literals** when a highlighting language style is selected. This happends not only for Lua but others languages as well (e.g. C# and its `@"multiline string literal";`). there is probably no easy way to fix this. I suggest to open a ticket with them.

Some pointers:

In [Scintilla.h](https://github.com/LuaDist/scintilla/blob/master/include/SciLexer.h) is defined

```
#define SCE_LUA_LITERALSTRING 8
```

and in DsSpellCheck's [SpellChecker.cpp](https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck/blob/master/src/SpellChecker.cpp)

```
if (category != SciUtils::StyleCategory::text && !((category == SciUtils::StyleCategory::comment && m_settings.check_comments) ||
  (category == SciUtils::StyleCategory::string && m_settings.check_strings) ||
  (category == SciUtils::StyleCategory::identifier && m_settings.check_variable_functions))) {
```

However, it is possible that Scintilla does not expose the string property of Lua string literals properly..